Terminology for stringed notes between the nut and the head tuners
After the end of the guitar fretboard, it is still possible to attack each string in this little space between the nut and the tuners.
What is the name of this technique/notes?
I thought of harmonics because it sounds similar but I can be wrong?
(Some models also have other notes between the higher bridge and the tailpiece).

I think by “between the higher bridge and the lower bridge” you mean “between the bridge and the tailpiece”?

@ToddWilcox - I think not, as nut and tuners are mentioned - unless of course it's a headless guitar!

@Tim Not sure why you answered when my question was for the OP, but based on their edit, yes they did mean “tailpiece”.

@ToddWilcox - only trying to be helpful! But OP seems to have confused tailpiece with headstock, not that you ever could! It's still not crystal clear  - to me! As only two of my guitars actually have pluckable string lengths between the bridge and the ball ends.

@Tim They wrote “between the higher bridge and lower bridge” and then changed it to “between higher bridge and tailpiece” so they did not in any way confuse the tailpiece and the headstock. The part about two bridges is at the complete opposite end of the guitar from the headstock.

I would just call it plucking or strumming behind/above the nut.  If anyone were to have a fancy Italian word for this, it would be violinists, but even for violin, I see this called "pizzicato above the nut".
The actual pitches vary greatly from instrument to instrument, and they also depend on which strings and tuning you are using.

I recently wrote this into a piece and simply put “play above the nut” above the first note of the passage.
